# PHP функция pack() на пальцах

Tags: php

Читаю книгу Котерова, там описание функции `pack`, я ни разу ее не использовал на практике и как мне кажется даже в чужом коде не встречал. Может кто то на пальцах объяснить зачем может она понадобится, для решения какой задачи? Зачем паковать и распаковывать в бинарную строку?

Comment: запись/чтение структуры данных целиком куда-либо, или получение например, пакета данных с устройства и его раскодирование. Описано у вас в API например, что приоходят данные где 1байт обозначает то-то, далее целое 2 байта, и т..п. вы это с соответствии с форматом сможете раскодировать без каких-либо обращений к памяти по смещениям и длине данных. и с кодированием то же самое.

Comment: Для формирования, например двоичных zip (в старых версиях пхп неоч хороший пример http://github.com/WhatCD/Gazelle/blob/master/classes/zip.class.php) или xls файлов http://gist.github.com/ihumanable/929039. Или любых других двоичных файлов, не используя генератор. Так же можно, например подшивать к двоичным файлам какую-то инфу, например строку "авторство" (скачано с такого-то сайта) в mp3, или в jpg.